Combining data present in multiple CSV files
I have multiple csv files having data as follows:
Sno,Country,2017-2018
1,AFGHANISTAN,287.1
2,ALGERIA,1286.4
3,AMERI SAMOA,9.09
4,ANGOLA,442.38
5,ARGENTINA,13881.75
6,AUSTRALIA,875706.78
7,AUSTRIA,10.45
8,AZERBAIJAN,147.87
.... so on

The 3rd column in each csv file denotes the data for that fiscal year. I have data across multiple years, 2014-2024 specifically, that I want to combine into 1 combined csv file.
Can someone help me figure out how to combine the csv files using Python and pandas?
I tried using pandas to concat the tables but the values do not get appended in the same row.
For example, Angola has the value 442.38 in column 2017-2018 but 0 in 2018-2019. But the value in year 2018-2019, 170.53, is added as a new row later in the file. I want the values for a specific country to be in the same row. Infact, the first year values are stored earlier and all the values in the next file are appended later in the csv.
import pandas as pd
import glob

file_path = 'file_name.csv'
csv_files = glob.glob(file_path)

# combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
combined_df = pd.read_csv("combined_data.csv")

for file in csv_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    
    if combined_df.empty:
        combined_df = df
    else:
        combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df,df],ignore_index=True)

combined_df = combined_df.fillna(0)
combined_df.to_csv('combined_data.csv', index=False)


please provide a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Your code is ok. It seems you have a problem with your data. It seems all your CSVs don;t have same columns

Hi @gtomer! Thanks for helping me out.
Yeah, my CSVs don't have the exact same columns. They have the following columns - Sno, Country, 20xx-20x(x+1)
The 3rd column is differing across the CSVs as it describes the value for that fiscal year.

If each country is a row and you "want the values for a specific country to be in the same row", you need to merge the different files, not concat.
merge performs a left-merge by default, so if the files contain different countries, use how='outer'.
import io
import pandas as pd

csv1 = """Sno,Country,2017-2018
1,AFGHANISTAN,287.1
2,ALGERIA,1286.4
3,AMERI SAMOA,9.09
4,ANGOLA,442.38
5,ARGENTINA,13881.75
6,AUSTRALIA,875706.78
7,AUSTRIA,10.45
8,AZERBAIJAN,147.87"""

csv2 = """Sno,Country,2019-2020
1,AFGHANISTAN,287.1
2,ALGERIA,1286.4
3,AMERI SAMOA,9.09
4,ANGOLA,442.38
5,ARGENTINA,13881.75
6,AUSTRALIA,875706.78
7,AUSTRIA,10.45"""

csv_files = [io.StringIO(csv) for csv in [csv1, csv2]]

df = pd.read_csv(csv_files[0])

for csv in csv_files[1:]:
    df = df.merge(pd.read_csv(csv), how="outer")

print(df)

   Sno      Country  2017-2018  2019-2020
0    1  AFGHANISTAN     287.10     287.10
1    2      ALGERIA    1286.40    1286.40
2    3  AMERI SAMOA       9.09       9.09
3    4       ANGOLA     442.38     442.38
4    5    ARGENTINA   13881.75   13881.75
5    6    AUSTRALIA  875706.78  875706.78
6    7      AUSTRIA      10.45      10.45
7    8   AZERBAIJAN     147.87        NaN


Hi! Sorry for the incredibly late reply to everyone who helped, lots of events in the last couple of weeks.
@e-motta, thanks for the help, I tried doing something similar but I am getting a weird output csv file where the number of rows is coming out to be roughly 900. The same row requirement is not satisfied. You have defined 2 csv's in the code itself, I have a list of csv file names and am trying to basically combine them all into 1 large csv file, I'm not too sure of where I'm going wrong.

@NilayKamat If you're doing the same thing as in my answer, that means your files have 900 different columns between them. You may want to normalize the names before merging. It's hard to say as I don't have access to the files. If that's not the case, you can create a minimal reproducible example (that is, with the least amount of data possible, it should show the same behavior you're experiencing with the actual data), and either edit this question or create a new one.
